# Powershell parse Website with nested elements

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, invoke-webrequest

I try to scrape a website using powershell.

```
[...]
<div class="school">
    <span class="count">52</span>
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
</div>
<div class="home">
    <span class="count">33</span>
    <span class="text">Some text</span>
</div>
[...]
```

I want to get the 52 from the span with the class "count" in the div with the class "school"

```
$url = 'https://url.com/something'
$html = Invoke-WebRequest $url
$school = $html.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') |
Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'school'}
```

Getting the "school" div is no problem. But I don't know how the walk the DOM further down. Adding

```
$school = $html.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') |
Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'school'} | getElementsByTagName('span') |
Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'count'}
```

doesn't work at all :/

Any suggestions?

```
$school = $html.ParsedHtml.body.getElementsByTagName('div') |
Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'school'}
$count = $school.getElementsByTagName('span') | 
Where {$_.getAttributeNode('class').Value -eq 'count'}
```

worked ... I don't know why my thoughts where so difficult :/

Comment: It doens't know what `getElementsByTagName('span')` is. Call on the method properly

Comment: Why not just use your browser developer tools to view the site source, select the node you what, and have the browser save/write the PS for you, Chrome and MSEdge have features/Add-Ons to do that for you. Search using  *** chrome 'save as PowerShell***, and first hit,  [Copy HTTP Requests from Chrome/Edge DevTools to PowerShell/cURL/Fetch](https://swimburger.net/blog/web/copy-http-requests-from-chrome-edge-devtools-to-powershell-curl-fetch#:~:text=Follow%20these%20steps%20to%20copy%20HTTP%20requests%20as,contents%20from%20your%20clipboard%20and%20hit%20enter.%20)

Comment: @postanote this looks very handy if I want to send data. But reading a value out of a page (or better dozens of slightly different pages) I can't think how to do :/
But never the less - this Add-On looks great

Comment: No worries, but without you pointing to a public site, which is implemented in the way you say you need to address, then any other response is just a guess. Many sites actively block some automation or all automation attempt of their properties, by design.  If that is the case for your target site, then there is little that can be done.